# Send image from Flask to React

Tags: python, reactjs, image, flask

I'm trying to send a randomly generated image from a flask API to my React frontend. I started by just saving the image every time I generate it to the file system then trying to access it with react but this doesn't work with the production build. Now I'm using flask's send_file(), but I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong on the frontend since this is my first React project.

In flask I have:

```
@main.route('/get-image', methods=['GET'])
def get_image():

    image_array = generate_random_image()
    img = Image.fromarray(image_array)
    img.save('img.png')
    return send_file('img.png', 'image/png')
```

and on the front end

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            image: '/get-image'
        };
    }

    updateImage() {
         fetch("/get-image").then(response => {
             this.setState({image: /** not sure what to have here **/});
         })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Image src={this.state.image} rounded/>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                <Container>
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Button onClick={() => this.updateImage()}>Original</Button>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It might be worth noting that I'm running React on `localhost:3000` and flask on `localhost:5000`. I have `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` in my `package.json` in the React directory.

Any advice? I tried a bunch of things on the react end but none worked. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: You should enable CORS on your backend. But only for development setup.

Comment: why would I need to enable CORS for dev, but not prod?

Comment: for security reasons

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Flask endpoint to return an image, you don't need to first save it to a file. You can return the image directly after setting appropriate header(s), most importantly `content-type`:

```py
from flask import request

@app.route("/get-image")
def image_endpoint():
    ...
    request.headers["content-type"] = "image/png"
    image = get_random_png_image_as_bytes()
    return image
```

Then you can load image directly:

```html
<img src="http://localhost:5000/get-image" />
```